# Implementing insert on BST by recursion for c++

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, tree, binary-search-tree

I was going through insertion of a node on BST recursively and I found an implementation below (check rinsert() function in the code below). The recursive function returns a pointer of the newly inserted node.

If the node is inserted lets say to the leaf node of height 4 for a tree. Shouldn't all the nodes along the path from height 3 to root be referencing some garbage pointer?

You can also find a test() function which actually returns a garbage pointer when the function doesn't run into an explicit return statement.

When I ran an inorder traversal using rinsert(), I was getting the BST without any garbage values.
Can anybody please help me understand what is going on in the rinsert() function?

```
struct Node  {
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    int key;

    Node(int key) {
        this->key = key;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
    }
};

class BST {

    Node* root;

    public:
        BST(int key) {
            root = new Node(key);
        }

        Node* rinsert(Node* cur, int key) {
            if (!cur) return new Node(key);

            if (key < cur->key)
                cur->left = rinsert(cur->left, key);
            else 
                cur->right = rinsert(cur->right, key);
        }

        void inorder(Node* node) {
            if (node == NULL) return;
            inorder(node->left);
            cout<<node->key<<" ";
            inorder(node->right);
        }

        Node* getRoot() {
            return root;
        }
};


// function to return garbage pointer
Node* test() {
    if (0) return new Node(2);
}

int main() {
    BST bst = BST(2);
    bst.rinsert(bst.getRoot(), 3);
    bst.rinsert(bst.getRoot(), 1);
    bst.rinsert(bst.getRoot(), 0);
    bst.rinsert(bst.getRoot(), 7);
    bst.rinsert(bst.getRoot(), 8);
    bst.rinsert(bst.getRoot(), 4);
    bst.rinsert(bst.getRoot(), 9);
    bst.inorder(bst.getRoot());

    // is it really a garbage pointer?
    Node* t = test();
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<t->key;
}
```

output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 7 8 9
253425920
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the function is bugged because although it promises to return a `Node*` it doesn't in all cases.

The correct code (untested) is

```
    Node* rinsert(Node* cur, int key) {
        if (!cur) return new Node(key);

        if (key < cur->key)
            cur->left = rinsert(cur->left, key);
        else 
            cur->right = rinsert(cur->right, key);
        return cur;                                 // new code
    }
```

The lack of a return statement means the posted code invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Unfortunately undefined behaviour does not mean a program will not work, it does not mean that the function will return a garbage pointer. Just by chance, in this case, the right pointer happens to be in the right register for the return value to be correct. So the code 'works'. On a different compiler (or even a different day) you might not be so lucky.

Comment: That explains a lot. Thanks.